# UIBarButtonItem size displays wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have custom `UINavigationBar`(for JSQMessagesViewController) with some items. But I have some problems with `leftBarButtonItem`

```
func setNavigationBar() {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 28, width: screenSize.width, height: 78))
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: chatName ?? "chat")
    let menuBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    menuBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 78, height: 78)
    menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "backButton"), for: .normal)
    menuBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuBtn)
    let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 78)
    currWidth?.isActive = true
    let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 78)
    currHeight?.isActive = true
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBarItem


    navBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Acrom-Bold", size: 26)!, .foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    navBar.isTranslucent = true

    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

But my BackButton looks wrong.
What is the problem with the height of the button?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If a bar button item has a custom view, you must size the width of the custom view using internal autolayout constraints.

But you must not size the height larger than the runtime likes, as you are doing. Delete these lines:

```
let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 78)
currHeight?.isActive = true
```

Comment: But I have: 
`let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 78)
    currWidth?.isActive = true
    let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 78)
    currHeight?.isActive = true `

Comment: And you're not also getting a complaint in the Xcode console?

Comment: I removed `constraint(equalToConstant: 78)` and and nothing has change. I don't get errors and complaints from Xcode console

Comment: I removed `menuBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 78, height: 78)` and add `constraint(equalToConstant: 78)` 

Get some console warnings: 
`"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a48a50 UILayoutGuide:0x6000030ad340'LeadingBarGuide(0x7ff5ef53dd00)'.height == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a66d00 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7ff5ef488890.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6000030ad340'LeadingBarGuide(0x7ff5ef53dd00)'.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a4a8a0 UIButton:0x7ff5ef59bab0.height == 78   (active)>" `